# How to add multiple labels to the x-axis of a D3 multiline chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, axes

I'm very new to D3 as I just started working with it a couple of days ago. I'm intrigued by the flexibility it provides as well as the ability to produce an extensive number of different charts and plots.

My first experiment has been to reproduce a critical Excel spreadsheet chart using mySQL data but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to create multiple x-axis labels.

I thought it was possible by adding a second x-axis, but it doesn't work.

```
var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d.bers + "<br />" + d.transport + "<br />" + d.power; })
    .orient("bottom");
```

The <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/K9CA8/)</kbd>, for your review. I placed the JSON data inside the fiddle as I'm not sure how the AJAX routine works from inside the JSFiddle site.

The result I am trying to achieve is pictured below, but I used a separate table to simulate the extra data labels in the x-axis. As you can tell, the scaling is off, which is why I believe it needs to be done via D3.

[image]

Comment: Your jsfiddle gives me an error. You may be able to get what you want by using the axis' [`.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat).

Comment: I believe I've fixed the error. I no longer use `d3.json` or `getJSON`. The data is static. I know what the `.tickFormat()` function does, the problem is where to use it to add to the X axis and how to use the other bits of data in those labels.

Comment: Random example with modified `.tickFormat` to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/KWRxW/1079/

Comment: Ah, I see... can I still make it two separate axes so that the `date` is vertical and the data is horizontal?

Comment: Yes. If you post a link to your updated fiddle we could have a look at the alignment issue.